# GEE in a NextJs monorepo on Vercel?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am currently trying out Earth Engine on the server side of a NextJs application. On localhost everything works well, but once I deploy everything to Vercel I got this error when trying to initiate GEE:

> EE ERROR Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open
> '.node-xmlhttprequest-sync-7'
> at Object.openSync (node:fs:601:3)
> at Object.writeFileSync (node:fs:2249:35)
> at exports.XMLHttpRequest.send (/var/task/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:477:10)
> at module$contents$ee$apiclient_apiclient.send (/var/task/node_modules/@google/earthengine/build/main.js:17928:13)
> at module$contents$ee$apiclient_EERequestService.send (/var/task/node_modules/@google/earthengine/build/main.js:17714:54)
> at module$exports$eeapiclient$promise_api_client.PromiseApiClient.$request
> (/var/task/node_modules/@google/earthengine/build/main.js:8842:69)
> at module$exports$eeapiclient$ee_api_client.ProjectsAlgorithmsApiClientImpl.list
> (/var/task/node_modules/@google/earthengine/build/main.js:13947:26)
> at ee.data.getAlgorithms (/var/task/node_modules/@google/earthengine/build/main.js:19606:40)
> at ee.ApiFunction.initialize (/var/task/node_modules/@google/earthengine/build/main.js:20631:78)
> at ee.ApiFunction.importApi (/var/task/node_modules/@google/earthengine/build/main.js:20639:18) {
> errno: -30,   syscall: 'open',   code: 'EROFS',   path:
> '.node-xmlhttprequest-sync-7' }

My understanding is that Vercel is only allowing files to be written within the `/tmp` directory, and otherwise is readonly.

Is there any way I could configure GEE so that it uses the `/tmp` directory for the temporarily authentication files, or is there some other way I could use GEE from a NextJs monorepo hosted on Vercel?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be related to the way `xmlhttprequest` handles the "syncrhonous" request. See my answer to my own question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77618205/3828592

In a nutshell, it might be that `process.argv[0]` is not what `xmlhttprequest` is expecting it to be.